# Pass variable to custom UITableViewCell from UIViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uitableview

Here is how I use my custom UITableViewCell `RunningTableViewCell` inside `UIViewController`:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! RunningTableViewCell

    //.......

    cell.isTop = false
    if(indexPath.row == 0){
        cell.isTop = true
    }

    cell.isBottom = false
    if(indexPath.row == myArray.count-1){
        cell.isBottom = true
    }

    return cell
}
```

And here is my `RunningTableViewCell` class: (Cell's GUI is made inside storyboard)

```
class RunningTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    //@IBOutlet ...
    @IBOutlet weak var myButton: SomeButton!

    var isTop: Bool?
    var isBottom: Bool?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        print("result: \(self.isTop) \(self.isBottom)")

        myButton.isTop = self.isTop
        myButton.isBottom = self.isBottom
    }
}
```

It returns `result: nil nil`

The usage of the result is: (`SomeButton` is a subview inside `RunningTableViewCell`)

```
class SomeButton: UIButton {
    var isTop = false
    var isBottom = false

    override func drawRect(rect: CGRect) {
        if(isTop){
            // DO SOMETHING...
        }
        if(isBottom){
            // DO SOMETHING...
        }
    }
}
```

So how can I pass data to RunningTableViewCell?

Comment: There are several methods to do, like if you set tag of cell to identify this cell is last or first.

Comment: @ilesh what if I want to pass more than 1 data? :)

Comment: It returns "result: nil nil" because `awakeFromNib` is called before you set the values in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

Comment: @pbasdf so where should I call in order to get the values set in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`?

Comment: @Arefly That depends on where/when/why you want the values.  Can you explain more of what you want to do?

Comment: @pbasdf I want to know if the current cell is the first/last cell and make changes on UI based on t. I also want to know some values that will be inside UI too. (see the updated question too) Thx :)

Comment: @Arefly I would try using a custom setter on the `isTop` and `isBottom` variables to update the UI as soon as those values change.

Comment: @pbasdf using `didSet` works at frist. But after I scroll up and down, the `isTop` and `isBottom` value become weird and confusing. I think it's the problem related to reuse cell?

Comment: @Arefly Yes, you have to be prepared for a cell that was at the top to be reused, potentially at the bottom.  Your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` should catch that, though use `if ... else ...` to avoid calling the setter twice.

Comment: @pbasdf you mean I have to have two cell with different identifier?

Comment: @Arefly That's another option, but it's not what I meant.  You currently set `isTop` to false, then set it true if the row is 0.  Just change that to `if (indexPath.row == 0) { cell.isTop = true } else { cell.isTop = false }` which avoids calling the `isTop` setter twice.

Comment: @pbasdf seems like still have same problem :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to override `prepareForReuse` in the cell. And remove it from `tableView:indexPath:`. So when you scroll the cell is going to be reused but the `isBotton` and `isTop` vars will be reseted.

```
override func prepareForReuse() {
    self.isBottom = false
    self.isTop = false
}
```

Comment: I can't find any difference after adding these code to `RunningTableViewCell`?

Comment: I guess you need to identify if the cell is the top cell or the bottom cell. That is going to be assigned later by the delegate method so `print("result: \(self.isTop) \(self.isBottom)")` is going to show always false (when the cell is created).

Answer (score 4):

`awakeFromNib` is called right after the view and its subviews were allocated and initialized.

So your code from `awakeFromNib` in `RunningTableViewCell` for each cell is called before delegate method `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`. That is why `isTop` and `isBottom` are `nil` in `awakeFromNib`.

You can define method in `RunningTableViewCell`, which will load cell with this variables.

```
func load(isTop: Bool, isBottom: Bool) {
    self.isTop = isTop
    self.isBottom = isBottom

    // Update cell UI as you wish
}
```

And finally rewrite delegate method `func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` in your view controller.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! RunningTableViewCell

    let isTop = indexPath.row == 0
    let isBottom = indexPath.row == myArray.count-1

    cell.load(isTop, isBottom: isBottom)

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Misternewb, Your answer worked perfect for my situation :)

Answer (score 1):

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("myCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! RunningTableViewCell

    //.......

    cell.isTop = false
    if(indexPath.row == 0){
        cell.isTop = true
        cell.tag=100
    }

    cell.isBottom = false
    if(indexPath.row == myArray.count-1){
        cell.isBottom = true
        cell.tag=200
    }

    return cell
}
```

and also get this like ...

```
class RunningTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

        //@IBOutlet ...

        var isTop: Bool?
        var isBottom: Bool?

        override func awakeFromNib() {
            super.awakeFromNib()
            if (self.tag==100)
            {
                isTop=true
            }
            else if (self.tag==200) {
                isBottom=true
            }
            else{
                isTop=false
                isBottom=false
            }

            print("result: \(self.isTop) \(self.isBottom)")
        }
    }
```

And also do using singleton methods...

Comment: what if I want to pass more than 1 data? :)

Comment: u r using `singleton` Methods

Comment: u can use  `singleton` Methods and  also using cell method custom method for setting values and its call from index path row tableview method. Thanks

Comment: the tag return `0` for all the time :(

Answer (score 1):

You can resolve this issue by call custom method in your cell like,

inside UIViewController:

```
//.......

cell.isTop = false
if(indexPath.row == 0){
    cell.isTop = true
}

cell.isBottom = false
if(indexPath.row == myArray.count-1){
    cell.isBottom = true
}

cell.UpdateViews()

return cell
}
```

inside TableViewCell:

```
//@IBOutlet ...

var isTop: Bool?
var isBottom: Bool?

func updateViews() {
  print("result: \(self.isTop) \(self.isBottom)")
}
```

Good luck!

Comment: still have the same problem with reusing cell :(

Comment: Oops! ... try set initial value when you define this valuables like this :             var isTop = false
var isBottom = false