# tableview keep returning the first cell as selected [swift]

Tags: swift, tableview

Here is my code:

```
var currentRow = 0
var cellTapped:Bool = true


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("CheckOutTableViewCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! CheckOutTableViewCell

    if indexPath.row == currentRow {

        if cellTapped == false {

            cell.checkBox.checkState = .Unchecked


        } else if cellTapped == true{

            cell.checkBox.checkState = .Checked

        }
    }
    else{

        cell.checkBox.checkState = .Unchecked

    }

    return cell as UITableViewCell
}
```

Every time my `tableview` sure will return the first cell as selected cell, why is it? What is the problem here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have write

```
var currentRow = 0
var cellTapped:Bool = true
```

So at this condition

```
if indexPath.row == currentRow 
cellTapped = true
```

it is true.

Try this

```
var cellTapped:Bool = false
```

Answer (score 0):

Cells are being reused. You need to create your own subclass for the cell and override `prepareForReuse()` and reset your selection in that cell. Look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35957199/pass-variable-to-custom-uitableviewcell-from-uiviewcontroller/35957365#35957365).

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for a way to select some rows in your table and make that visible with checkboxes?
Well, then there's an easier way to this without the hassle to manually work with reusage of cells and such.

Basically you set the property to let iOS do single or multiple selections `tableView.allowsSelection = true` or `tableView.allowsMultipleSelection = true`and then implement/ override the two functions `selectRowAtIndexPath` and `deselectRowAtIndexPath` of the tableView. Where you check and uncheck the checkboxes.

Have a look [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/index.html#//apple_ref/swift/cl/c:objc(cs)UITableView) in the UITableView Reference, chapter "Managing Selections". 
There's no need to control all the reusage and such by hand.